# OAuth state is missing or invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, oauth

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.ServerSideSessions.UserDisplayNameClaimType = "name";

    options.KeyManagement.SigningAlgorithms = new[]
    {
        new SigningAlgorithmOptions(SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256) { UseX509Certificate = true },
        new SigningAlgorithmOptions(SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSsaPssSha256),
        new SigningAlgorithmOptions(SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
    };
})
    .AddServerSideSessions()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<UserIdentity>()
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
        b.UseSqlServer(defaultConnString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(assembly));
    })
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(defaultConnString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(assembly));
    })
    .AddDynamicIdentityProviders()
    .AddDynamicGithubProvider()
    .AddDynamicGoogleProvider()
    .AddDynamicMicrosoftProvider()
    .AddSaml2DynamicProvider();
```

whith this code i try to add google as dynamic identity provider in identity server i know that identity server support by default the oidc but i need to configure many paramters in order to login with google or any other provider

```
public static class IdentityServerBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddDynamicIdentityProviders(
        this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddIdentityProviderStore<DynamicProviderStore>();
        return builder;
    }
    public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddSaml2DynamicProvider(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<IdentityServerOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.DynamicProviders.AddProviderType<Saml2Handler, Saml2Options, Saml2IdentityProvider>("Saml2");
        });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<Saml2Options>, Saml2ConfigureOptions>();
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<Saml2Options>, PostConfigureSaml2Options>());
        builder.Services.TryAddTransient<Saml2Handler>();
        return builder;
    }
    public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddDynamicGoogleProvider(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<IdentityServerOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.DynamicProviders.AddProviderType<GoogleHandler, GoogleOptions, GoogleProvider>("Google");
        });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>, GoogleConfigureOptions>();
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>, OAuthPostConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions,GoogleHandler>>());
        builder.Services.TryAddTransient<GoogleHandler>();
        return builder;
    }
    public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddDynamicMicrosoftProvider(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<IdentityServerOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.DynamicProviders.AddProviderType<MicrosoftAccountHandler, MicrosoftAccountOptions, MicrosoftProvider>("microsoft");
        });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MicrosoftAccountOptions>, MicrosoftAccountConfigureOptions>();
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<MicrosoftAccountOptions>, OAuthPostConfigureOptions<MicrosoftAccountOptions,MicrosoftAccountHandler>>());
        builder.Services.TryAddTransient<MicrosoftAccountHandler>();
        return builder;
    }
    public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddDynamicGithubProvider(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder) 
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<IdentityServerOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.DynamicProviders.AddProviderType<GitHubAuthenticationHandler, GitHubAuthenticationOptions, OidcProvider>("Github");
        });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<GitHubAuthenticationOptions>, GithubConfigureOptions>();
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<GitHubAuthenticationOptions>, OAuthPostConfigureOptions<GitHubAuthenticationOptions, GitHubAuthenticationHandler>>());
        builder.Services.TryAddTransient<GitHubAuthenticationHandler>();
        return builder;
    }
}
```

the code where i configure the options of the google provider

`

```
public class GoogleConfigureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<GoogleOptions>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
        public GoogleConfigureOptions(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public void Configure(GoogleOptions options)
        {
        }
        public void Configure(string? name, GoogleOptions options)
        {
            var providerOptions = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<DynamicProviderOptions>();
            var context = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IdentityServerConfigurationDbContext>();
            var idp =  context?
                            .IdentityProviders
                            .Where(idp => idp.Type == "google").FirstOrDefault();
            options.ClientId = "";
            options.ClientSecret = "";
            options.SignInScheme = providerOptions?.SignInScheme;
        }
    }
```

middlewares :

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

my probleme is that when i try to login for example with google i redirected to the google login page i finish the process of the login but whene i redirected to my application i got an error which is :This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5443/signin-google?state=CfDJ8C636nO23ZVEmrAoODII5ZAlegDXbXt-wyNrPVlrc_L3L40IWOVjxG6J_VCLOXi7bqKc2O5-jJuQjF6bL3iMd074XFqnLiJC293E5eLph_vBd20Z9Axwd_j2Rp3H-e5orUseiZkv9EzOBEWnknntd1zaxAg3oCyEoAg5Xe7t9WGyqybdcw6EZ5yve-kz8V8rks8FiFH6vo-hK1SKydJWvstDguc2B__pbySLIGuUSmn9FSPOh5q3NvQVlaFOOqjqeC6n8LaawJUsr-NB-5sut94YAuwl1daNP_G0OsEUJurx&code=4%2F0AfJohXm4iklpoebyovzVLrOiIIoucLHWqFuy-ews5gtvKWCEasvRaaKOLNhkewU6lO-slQ&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&hd=horizon-tech.tn&prompt=none